# Failed to read candidate component class in GRAILS after update 2.3 --> 2.4.3

Tags: spring, grails, groovy

I have updated my grails app from 2.3.0 to 2.4.3 following the instructions given.

When I want to run the app I get an error that looks according to my research like a version conflict in SPRING. But if i look at the dependency tree it does not look like a dependency conflict any ideas?

Here are my dependencies/plugins:

```
 dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
         compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.2'
         compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.34'
         runtime 'org.ostermiller:utils:1.07.00'
         compile 'org.webjars:jquery:2.1.3'
         runtime 'net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:2.9.0' 
         compile 'org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.4.RELEASE'
         compile 'org.springframework:spring-web:4.1.4.RELEASE'
         runtime 'net.sourceforge.htmlcleaner:htmlcleaner:2.5'
         //compile 'org.grails:grails-plugin-rest:2.4.3'

    }

    plugins {

        // plugins for the compile step
        compile ':scaffolding:2.1.0'
        compile ':cache:1.1.3'
        compile ':asset-pipeline:1.8.3'


        runtime ":resources:1.2.13"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
        runtime ":html-cleaner:0.2"
        build ":tomcat:7.0.54"
        runtime  ":hibernate:3.6.10.18"
        //compile ":rest:0.8"
    }
```

Additionally here the stacktrace:

```
|Loading Grails 2.4.3
|Configuring classpath
.
|Environment set to development
.................................
|Packaging Grails application
..
|Compiling 10 source files
.Error 
|
Fatal error during compilation org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException: Compilation Failed (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/C:/Development/Grails/grails-2.4.3/dist/grails-plugin-rest-2.4.3.jar!/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/compiler/web/rest/ControllerRestTransformer.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class org.springframework.core.type.classreading.AnnotationMetadataReadingVisitor does not implement the requested interface org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:301)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:242)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.scan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:220)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBuilder.invokeMethod(GantBuilder.java:99)
    at _GrailsCompile$_run_closure3_closure8_closure9.doCall(_GrailsCompile.groovy:61)
    at _GrailsCompile$_run_closure3_closure8_closure9.doCall(_GrailsCompile.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at _GrailsCompile.withCompilationErrorHandling(_GrailsCompile.groovy:68)
    at _GrailsCompile.this$4$withCompilationErrorHandling(_GrailsCompile.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:168)
    at _GrailsCompile$_run_closure3_closure8.doCall(_GrailsCompile.groovy:60)
    at _GrailsCompile$_run_closure3_closure8.doCall(_GrailsCompile.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at _GrailsCompile$_run_closure3.doCall(_GrailsCompile.groovy:57)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processClosure(GantMetaClass.java:81)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processArgument(GantMetaClass.java:95)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:128)
    at _GrailsCompile$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsCompile.groovy:44)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:168)
    at _GrailsPackage$_run_closure2_closure8.doCall(_GrailsPackage.groovy:42)
    at _GrailsPackage$_run_closure2_closure8.doCall(_GrailsPackage.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at _GrailsPackage$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsPackage.groovy:41)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
```

...

```
Error |
Fatal error during compilation org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException: Compilation Failed
```

and last but not least here is the dependency report:

```
   |Loading Grails 2.4.3
|Configuring classpath
.
|Environment set to development
.
build - Dependencies for the build system only (total: 35)
+--- xalan:serializer:2.7.1
+--- org.grails:grails-bootstrap:2.4.3
|    \--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.5
|    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5
|    \--- jline:jline:2.12
|    \--- org.apache.ant:ant:1.8.4
|    \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.6
|    \--- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:1.8.4
|    \--- org.apache.ant:ant-trax:1.7.1
|    \--- org.apache.ant:ant-junit:1.8.4
|    \--- net.java.dev.jna:jna:4.0.0
|    \--- org.codehaus.gant:gant_groovy1.8:1.9.6
|    \--- org.apache.ivy:ivy:2.3.0
|    \--- org.fusesource.jansi:jansi:1.11
+--- org.grails:grails-project-api:2.4.3
+--- org.grails:grails-scripts:2.4.3
|    \--- org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0
|         \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
+--- org.grails:grails-docs:2.4.3
|    \--- org.xhtmlrenderer:core-renderer:R8
|    \--- org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.8
|    \--- org.grails:grails-gdoc-engine:1.0.1
|    \--- org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.3
|    \--- com.lowagie:itext:2.0.8
|         \--- bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:138
|         \--- bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:138
|    \--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6
+--- org.grails.plugins:tomcat:7.0.54
|    \--- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-catalina-ant:7.0.53
|    \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:7.0.53
|         \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:7.0.53
|    \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-log4j:7.0.53
|    \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:7.0.53
|    \--- org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler:ecj:3.7.2
|    \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:7.0.53


provided - Dependencies needed at development time, but not during deployment (total: 1)
+--- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1


compile - Dependencies placed on the classpath for compilation (total: 76)
+--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.6
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-rest:2.4.3
|    \--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.5
|    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-datasource:2.4.3
|         \--- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:7.0.50
|              \--- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:7.0.50
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.0.6.RELEASE
|    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4
|    \--- org.grails:grails-web:2.4.3
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-sitemesh:2.4.3
|              \--- opensymphony:sitemesh:2.4
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-databinding:2.4.3
|              \--- org.grails:grails-databinding:2.4.3
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-mvc:2.4.3
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-common:2.4.3
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-context-support:4.0.6.RELEASE
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.0.6.RELEASE
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-fileupload:2.4.3
|              \--- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.3.1
|                   \--- commons-io:commons-io:2.2
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-jsp:2.4.3
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-url-mappings:2.4.3
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-gsp:2.4.3
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-controllers:2.4.3
|         \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-validation:2.4.3
|         \--- org.grails:grails-async:2.4.3
|              \--- org.codehaus.gpars:gpars:1.2.1
|                   \--- org.codehaus.jsr166-mirror:jsr166y:1.7.0
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding:2.4.3
|    \--- org.grails:grails-core:2.4.3
|         \--- org.grails:grails-bootstrap:2.4.3
|         \--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
|         \--- org.grails:grails-spring:2.4.3
|         \--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-i18n:2.4.3
|    \--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-filters:2.4.3
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-gsp:2.4.3
|    \--- org.grails:grails-web-gsp-taglib:2.4.3
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-codecs:2.4.3
|         \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.6
|         \--- org.grails:grails-encoder:2.4.3
|    \--- org.grails:grails-logging:2.4.3
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-log4j:2.4.3
|    \--- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.5
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-services:2.4.3
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-tx:4.0.6.RELEASE
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-servlets:2.4.3
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings:2.4.3
|    \--- com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4
|    \--- org.grails:grails-validation:2.4.3
|         \--- commons-validator:commons-validator:1.4.0
+--- org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.2
+--- mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.34
+--- org.webjars:jquery:2.1.3
+--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.0.6.RELEASE
|    \--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.3
+--- org.springframework:spring-web:4.0.6.RELEASE
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.0.6.RELEASE
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.0.6.RELEASE
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.0.6.RELEASE
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:4.0.6.RELEASE
+--- org.grails.plugins:scaffolding:2.1.0
+--- org.grails.plugins:cache:1.1.3
|    \--- cglib:cglib-nodep:2.2.2
|    \--- org.grails.plugins:webxml:1.4.1
+--- org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline:1.8.3


runtime - Dependencies needed at runtime but not for compilation (total: 110)
+--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.6
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-rest:2.4.3
|    \--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.5
|    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-datasource:2.4.3
|         \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-log4j:7.0.50
|         \--- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:7.0.50
|              \--- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:7.0.50
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.0.6.RELEASE
|    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4
|    \--- org.grails:grails-web:2.4.3
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-sitemesh:2.4.3
|              \--- opensymphony:sitemesh:2.4
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-databinding:2.4.3
|              \--- org.grails:grails-databinding:2.4.3
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-mvc:2.4.3
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-common:2.4.3
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-context-support:4.0.6.RELEASE
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.0.6.RELEASE
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-aspects:4.0.6.RELEASE
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-fileupload:2.4.3
|              \--- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.3.1
|                   \--- commons-io:commons-io:2.2
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-jsp:2.4.3
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-url-mappings:2.4.3
|         \--- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.1
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-gsp:2.4.3
|         \--- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.1
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-controllers:2.4.3
|         \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-validation:2.4.3
|         \--- org.grails:grails-async:2.4.3
|              \--- org.codehaus.gpars:gpars:1.2.1
|                   \--- org.codehaus.jsr166-mirror:jsr166y:1.7.0
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding:2.4.3
|    \--- org.grails:grails-core:2.4.3
|         \--- xalan:serializer:2.7.1
|         \--- org.grails:grails-bootstrap:2.4.3
|         \--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
|         \--- org.grails:grails-spring:2.4.3
|         \--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-i18n:2.4.3
|    \--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-filters:2.4.3
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-gsp:2.4.3
|    \--- org.grails:grails-web-gsp-taglib:2.4.3
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-codecs:2.4.3
|         \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.6
|         \--- org.grails:grails-encoder:2.4.3
|    \--- org.grails:grails-logging:2.4.3
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-log4j:2.4.3
|    \--- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.5
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-services:2.4.3
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-tx:4.0.6.RELEASE
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-servlets:2.4.3
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings:2.4.3
|    \--- com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4
|    \--- org.grails:grails-validation:2.4.3
|         \--- commons-validator:commons-validator:1.4.0
+--- com.h2database:h2:1.3.176
+--- log4j:log4j:1.2.17
+--- org.grails:grails-resources:2.4.3
+--- org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.2
+--- mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.34
+--- org.ostermiller:utils:1.07.00
+--- org.webjars:jquery:2.1.3
+--- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:2.9.0
+--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.0.6.RELEASE
|    \--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.3
+--- org.springframework:spring-web:4.0.6.RELEASE
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.0.6.RELEASE
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.0.6.RELEASE
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.0.6.RELEASE
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:4.0.6.RELEASE
+--- net.sourceforge.htmlcleaner:htmlcleaner:2.5
|    \--- org.jdom:jdom2:2.0.4
+--- org.grails.plugins:scaffolding:2.1.0
+--- org.grails.plugins:cache:1.1.3
|    \--- cglib:cglib-nodep:2.2.2
|    \--- org.grails.plugins:webxml:1.4.1
+--- org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline:1.8.3
|    \--- org.mozilla:rhino:1.7R4
+--- org.grails.plugins:resources:1.2.13
+--- org.grails.plugins:database-migration:1.4.0
|    \--- org.liquibase:liquibase-core:2.0.5
+--- org.grails.plugins:html-cleaner:0.2
+--- org.grails.plugins:hibernate:3.6.10.18
|    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:3.6.10.Final
|    \--- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:2.4.8
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-core:3.1.3.RELEASE
|         \--- org.javassist:javassist:3.17.1-GA
|         \--- javax.transaction:jta:1.1
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm:3.1.3.RELEASE
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate:3.1.3.RELEASE
|         \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate-core:3.1.3.RELEASE
|              \--- antlr:antlr:2.7.7
|              \--- dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1
|              \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-plugin-support:3.1.3.RELEASE
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-orm:4.0.6.RELEASE
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-simple:3.1.3.RELEASE
|    \--- commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1
|    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:3.6.10.Final
|    \--- javax.validation:validation-api:1.0.0.GA
|    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:4.1.0.Final
|    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:3.6.10.Final
|         \--- cglib:cglib:2.2
|              \--- asm:asm:3.1
|    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:3.2.0.Final


test - Dependencies needed for test compilation and execution but not at runtime (total: 124)
+--- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1
+--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.6
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-rest:2.4.3
|    \--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.5
|    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-datasource:2.4.3
|         \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-log4j:7.0.50
|         \--- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:7.0.50
|              \--- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:7.0.50
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.0.6.RELEASE
|    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4
|    \--- org.grails:grails-web:2.4.3
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-sitemesh:2.4.3
|              \--- opensymphony:sitemesh:2.4
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-databinding:2.4.3
|              \--- org.grails:grails-databinding:2.4.3
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-mvc:2.4.3
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-common:2.4.3
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-context-support:4.0.6.RELEASE
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.0.6.RELEASE
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-aspects:4.0.6.RELEASE
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-fileupload:2.4.3
|              \--- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.3.1
|                   \--- commons-io:commons-io:2.2
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-jsp:2.4.3
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-url-mappings:2.4.3
|         \--- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.1
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-gsp:2.4.3
|         \--- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.1
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-controllers:2.4.3
|         \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-validation:2.4.3
|         \--- org.grails:grails-async:2.4.3
|              \--- org.codehaus.gpars:gpars:1.2.1
|                   \--- org.codehaus.jsr166-mirror:jsr166y:1.7.0
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding:2.4.3
|    \--- org.grails:grails-core:2.4.3
|         \--- xalan:serializer:2.7.1
|         \--- org.grails:grails-bootstrap:2.4.3
|         \--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
|         \--- org.grails:grails-spring:2.4.3
|         \--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-i18n:2.4.3
|    \--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-filters:2.4.3
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-gsp:2.4.3
|    \--- org.grails:grails-web-gsp-taglib:2.4.3
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-codecs:2.4.3
|         \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.6
|         \--- org.grails:grails-encoder:2.4.3
|    \--- org.grails:grails-logging:2.4.3
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-log4j:2.4.3
|    \--- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.5
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-services:2.4.3
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-tx:4.0.6.RELEASE
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-servlets:2.4.3
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings:2.4.3
|    \--- com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4
|    \--- org.grails:grails-validation:2.4.3
|         \--- commons-validator:commons-validator:1.4.0
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-testing:2.4.3
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-domain-class:2.4.3
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-converters:2.4.3
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-test:4.0.6.RELEASE
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-mimetypes:2.4.3
|    \--- org.grails:grails-test:2.4.3
|         \--- org.objenesis:objenesis:1.4
|         \--- org.grails:grails-project-api:2.4.3
|              \--- org.apache.ant:ant:1.8.4
|                   \--- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:1.8.4
|              \--- jline:jline:2.12
|              \--- org.codehaus.gant:gant_groovy1.8:1.9.6
|              \--- org.fusesource.jansi:jansi:1.11
+--- org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0
|    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
+--- junit:junit:4.11
+--- com.h2database:h2:1.3.176
+--- log4j:log4j:1.2.17
+--- org.grails:grails-resources:2.4.3
+--- org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.2
+--- mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.34
+--- org.ostermiller:utils:1.07.00
+--- org.webjars:jquery:2.1.3
+--- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:2.9.0
+--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.0.6.RELEASE
|    \--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.3
+--- org.springframework:spring-web:4.0.6.RELEASE
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.0.6.RELEASE
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.0.6.RELEASE
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.0.6.RELEASE
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:4.0.6.RELEASE
+--- net.sourceforge.htmlcleaner:htmlcleaner:2.5
|    \--- org.jdom:jdom2:2.0.4
+--- org.grails.plugins:scaffolding:2.1.0
+--- org.grails.plugins:cache:1.1.3
|    \--- cglib:cglib-nodep:2.2.2
|    \--- org.grails.plugins:webxml:1.4.1
+--- org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline:1.8.3
|    \--- org.mozilla:rhino:1.7R4
+--- org.grails.plugins:resources:1.2.13
+--- org.grails.plugins:database-migration:1.4.0
|    \--- org.liquibase:liquibase-core:2.0.5
+--- org.grails.plugins:html-cleaner:0.2
+--- org.grails.plugins:hibernate:3.6.10.18
|    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:3.6.10.Final
|    \--- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:2.4.8
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-core:3.1.3.RELEASE
|         \--- org.javassist:javassist:3.17.1-GA
|         \--- javax.transaction:jta:1.1
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm:3.1.3.RELEASE
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate:3.1.3.RELEASE
|         \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate-core:3.1.3.RELEASE
|              \--- antlr:antlr:2.7.7
|              \--- dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1
|              \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-plugin-support:3.1.3.RELEASE
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-orm:4.0.6.RELEASE
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-simple:3.1.3.RELEASE
|    \--- commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1
|    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:3.6.10.Final
|    \--- javax.validation:validation-api:1.0.0.GA
|    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:4.1.0.Final
|    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:3.6.10.Final
|         \--- cglib:cglib:2.2
|              \--- asm:asm:3.1
|    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:3.2.0.Final
```

Comment: Tried `grails clean`?

Comment: Well I do see different versions of spring being mixed, 4.1.4 and 4.0.6. Don't mix spring versions.

Comment: @tim: yes, cleaned - deleted .grails folder etc.. No effect

Comment: @m.Deinum thank you also for your answer. Unfortunately the problem is not solved. I changed everything to 4.0.6. but the same error occurs. The new dependency tree updated above

Comment: I have now even added excludes for all spring modules to all plugins and the same error occurs.. So it does not seem to be related to the spring dependencies:

{ excludes 'spring-expression', 'spring-core', 'spring-context', 'spring-tx', 'spring-aop', 'spring-jdbc', 'spring-web', 'spring-test', 'aspectjrt', 'aspectjweaver', 'cglib-nodep', 'ehcache', 'commons-collections','hsqldb', 'jsr250-api', 'log4j', 'junit', 'mockito-core', 'jmock-junit4'}

Comment: Well it is related to spring because the error you get is due to the fact that what was once an interface is now an abstract class (in ASM 4.0 which is inlined in Spring as of Spring 4). See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462718/nested-exception-is-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror-org-springframework and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758151/class-conflict-when-starting-up-java-project-classmetadatareadingvisitor-has-in. Maybe an old plugin somewhere?

Comment: @all solved it: also it was not needed, I had an old spring 3.2 jar in the lib folder